# How to Count calculated work hours in one month for each labors

Tags: mysql, count, computed-column

Good Day.

I have some data like bellow

```
id name            in                  out
1  lala    2023-09-29 07:00:00   2023-09-29 17:00:00
2  lili    2023-09-29 07:30:00   2023-09-29 16:00:00
1  lala    2023-09-30 07:00:00   2023-09-30 17:30:00
2  lili    2023-09-30 07:00:00   2023-09-30 16:00:00
```

how to calculate total work hours even different day on example table record.
the result i wanted like bellow.

```
id   name   total_hours
1   lala        20.5
2   lili        17.5
```

i also try to use this query

```
SELECT global_id as id, 
       beacon_name,IFNULL(MIN(case when in_out_flag = 'IN' then received_date end),"") as in, 
       IFNULL(MAX(case when in_out_flag = 'OUT' then received_date end),"") as out 
WHERE (date(received_date) 
BETWEEN '2023-07-01' and '2023-07-05') 
group by global_id ,date(received_date);
```

but I only get the record per day only, i want to get all total work hours in one month.

Thank You.
Regards.

Comment: Your data examples and expected result doesn't match. You haven't include `in_out_flag` and `received_date`  columns. Note in your case would be better to have `recieved_date` column as date datatype , or add another column in your table with date data type so it can be used by the optimiser in the where condition

Comment: Hai Ergest,
in_out_flag just only text status (In or Out) in myTable. My focus is to grouping the id become one and count total work hours day by day. Thank You